# Format bold text

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm building a telegram bot with python, in particular with python-telegram-bot. I would like to format a part of my output text as bold: I know that exists this syntax:

```py
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="*bold* Example message", 
                parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

However this works great with string literals, but what I put as input of bot.send_message() is a concatenation of strings fetched from variables. Is there an alternative way to print just a part of the concatenation in bold?

Comment: Concat the `"*"` string with your variable and then concat another `"*"` at the end

Comment: @MR.Garcia it was so simple, thank you so much you saved my day!